# AngularJS: obtain underlying progression of an "asynchronous" call via promises

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, angular-promise

So, we currently have something like this at for asynchronous petitions to a backend.

First: a **GenericApi** for all the aplications

```
get: function (url) { 
        return api_bridge ({
          execute: function (auth_headers) {
            return $q.resolve($http.get(vm.urlBase + url, {headers: auth_headers}));
          } 
        }).then(handlerSuccessResponse, handlerErrorResponse);
      }
```

and then handler methods

```
//error
function handlerErrorResponse(response) {     
  return $q.reject(response); 
}

//success
function handlerSuccessResponse(response) {
  if (response.isAsync) {
      return asyncStatus(response.taskId);
  } else {
      return $q.resolve(response);
  }
}
```

Success got the key here, since if it is an async method, just recursively calls this method:

```
function asyncStatus(id){
  return getAsyncStatus(id).then(function(response){
    if (response.progress < 100){
      return asyncStatus(id); 
    } else {
      return getAsyncResult(id);
    }
  });
}
```

which calls either of those:

```
  getAsyncStatus: function(id){
    return get('/async/status/' + id);
  },

  getAsyncResult: function(id){
    return get('/async/result/' + id);
  },
```

(which call the first method of this list again).

And this way we can do a getter in such a way we don't ever care what happens under the hood:

```
  get("/myurl")
  .then(successMethod)
  .catch(errorMethod);
```

(This will work same way whether it is asynchronous or not)

But now we would like to upgrade this system to be able to make callbacks everytime an asyncStatus call is made. Ideally something like this:

```
  get("/myurl")
  .then(successMethod)
  .catch(errorMethod)
  .progression(progressMethod);
```

The obvious way would be to pass a method as an argument through all the chain and then call it in every iteration of **getAsyncStatus**, but that kind of defeats the purpose of all this which is having a black box under the hood no one needs to worry about, plus changing this would imply changing all the current existing methods.

To make it the closest possible to the example I guess I would have to do something with $q.defer().notify() but I can't seem to grasp the concept right. Doing this doesn't work:

```
  get("/myurl")
  .then(successMethod, null, progressMethod)
  .catch(errorMethod);
```

I have no clue how to make it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, apparently api_bridge method was breaking the promise binding. Found the solution is doing this:

Generic **get**:

```
get: function (url) { 
        var dfr = $q.defer();
        dfr.resolve( api_bridge ({
          execute: function (auth_headers) {
          return $q.resolve($http.get(vm.urlBase + url, {headers: auth_headers}));
          } 
        }));
        return dfr.promise.then(handlerSuccessResponse, handlerErrorResponse);
      }
```

Handler methods (no change):

```
//error
function handlerErrorResponse(response) {     
  return $q.reject(response); 
}

//success
function handlerSuccessResponse(response) {
  if (response.isAsync) {
      return asyncStatus(response.taskId);
  } else {
      return $q.resolve(response);
  }
}
```

Recursive async method:

```
function asyncStatus(id){
  var deferred = $q.defer();
  var deferred.promise.then(null, null, angular.noop);
  var deferred.notify("This is a notification");
  deferred.resolve(getAsyncStatus(id).then(function(response){
    if (response.progress < 100){
      return asyncStatus(id); 
    } else {
      return getAsyncResult(id);
    }
  }));
  return deferred.promise;
}
```

which calls either of those (no change);

```
  getAsyncStatus: function(id){
    return get('/async/status/' + id);
  },

  getAsyncResult: function(id){
    return get('/async/result/' + id);
  },
```

And now we can do:

```
get("/myurl")
  .then(successMethod, null, progressMethod)
  .catch(errorMethod);
```

Callback **progressMethod** will be called everytime asyncStatus throws a notification.